# Jquery Dialog and asp.net dropdownlist z-index issue in IE6

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I created jquery popup dialog and asp.net dropdownlist control in my aspx page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#div_popup').dialog({     
            resizable: true,               
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            position: 'center',
            zIndex: 10000              
        });

    });
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css" >
    #div_dropdownlist
    {
        margin-left : 50%;
        margin-top : 50%;     
        z-index: -1;        
    }
    #div_popup
    {}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="div_dropdownlist">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlList" Width="200px"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div id="div_popup">
        My test Popup
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My purpose is to show jquery dialog popup over every other controls when you drag it over other controls.
Everything work well in every browsers but IE6.

[image]

I tried css zIndex. But it has no effect in IE6.

So, please let me know how I can make it correct in IE6.

**Updated**

I changed my div popup style to

```
#div_popup
    {
        z-index: 10000;        
    }
```

and I had changed my jquery dialog css style to

```
$('#div_popup').dialog({     
            ...

            zIndex: 10000              
        });
```

But in IE6, that jquery popup cannot display over asp.net dropdown list box when I drage over that control.

For your reference , here is [my_source_code](http://www.mediafire.com/?pfbmydqmo1xh093).

Comment: Did you try to change the Z-index on the popup, instead of the Dropdown?

Comment: Hi @EliteGamer please kindly see my updated code again.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/
There is an ie bug and the select boxes shows on top.
I would hide the select box as suggested or use an shim for ie6.